# @ValidateConnection method is failing to be called when using "@Category component"

Tags: mule, devkit

I have an issue in a new devkit Project where the following  @ValidateConnection  method is failing to be called (but my @processor methods are called fine when requested in the flows)

```
 @ValidateConnection
    public boolean isConnected() {
        return isConnected;
    }
```

I thought that the above should be called to check whether to call the @Connect method.

I think it is because I am using a non default category (Components) for the connector

```
@Category(name = "org.mule.tooling.category.core", description = "Components")
```

And the resulting Behavoir is different to what I am used to with DevKit in Cloud connector mode.

I guess I will need to do checks in each @processor for now to see if the initialization logic is done, as there doesn't seem to be an easy way to run a one time config.

EDIT_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**
I actually tried porting it back to a cloud connector @cat and the same behaviour, maybe its an issue with devkit -DarchetypeVersion=3.4.0, I used 3.2.x somthing before and things worked a bit better

Answer (score 1):

The `@ValidateConnection` annotated method in the `@Connector` is called at the end of the `makeObject()` method of the generated `*ConnectionFactory` class. If you look for references of who is calling your `isConnected()` you should be able to confirm this.

So no, you should not need to perform the checks, it should be done automatically for you.

There must be something else missing... do you have a `@ConnectionIdentifier` annotated method?

PS. `@Category` annotation is purely for cosmetic purposes in Studio.

Comment: will check tomorrow, I do know that adding @ConnectionIdentifier didn't make a difference..

Comment: interestingly doing a text search for isConnected didn't result in any matches in the generated sources.

Comment: That's bad IMO, there's an issue somewhere. Also doesn't your IDE have reference search? :)

Comment: eclipse ctrl+shift +G is unfruitful in this case, text search just finds matches in the apiDOcs

Comment: We will just have a workaround for now, doing init checks in each @proc method. Maybe next devKit project it will work, for now DevKit seems a bit hap hazord. But it beats doing connectors the old way

Comment: That sucks: **do not do that**. DevKit works, we need to find out why it doesn't in your particular case, which is hard with the partial information you're providing. Can you share your Maven project somewhere?

Comment: Hmm for some reason time there is no FooConnectionManager class generated like my last successful devKit project

Comment: in the gen'ed **adaptor** package I only have the classes **[HttpCallbackAdapter.java, PoolManager.java]** wheras in the other successful project: **[FooCapabilitiesAdapter.java,FooConnectionManager.java,FooInjectionAdapter.java,FooLifecycleAdapter.java]**

Comment: there are all these other packages created also like **[oauth,config,connection,devkit..etc]** created, its like nothing specific to my project is generated.

Comment: Indeed, there is a problem. Can you show the relevant parts of your POM? Maybe it's just a config issue?